# any two simply connected open set in the plane R^2 are diffeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Prove that any two simply connected open set in the plane R^2 are diffeomorphic. I know that in the complex plane any simply connected open set is diffeomorphic to either complex plane or open unit disk.How to adapt the proof here.
edited later

Also
I need to show that:
C considered as a complex-analytic manifold is not isomorphic to the unit disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the fact that any simply connected open set is diffeomorphic to $D$, the complex unit disc.  (And clearly $\mathbb{C} \simeq D$).

Given two sets $S$ and $S'$, we have diffeomorphisms $\varphi$ and $\psi'$, from $S$ (resp. $S'$) to $D$.  These maps are bijective, and thus invertible.  The inverse of a diffeomorphism is again a diffeomorphism, so $\varphi^{-1}$ and $\psi^{-1}$ are diffeomorphisms.  We may now take the map $$\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}: S \to D \to S'$$which is again a diffeomorphism, and it is proved.

Comment: is it C≃D? I think it is not.but I think R^2≃D and that is I think one of the necessary things to be shown

Comment: If you're looking at the standard (metric topology), they are the same (homeomorphic).  And yes, $\mathbb{C} \simeq D$ by the map $\frac{z}{1-|z|^2} : D \to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You may look at $\mathbb{C}$ as $(\mathbb{R}^2, + , *)$ where $(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac-bd, ad + bc)$.

Comment: i have sorted out my confusion. please help me with the newly added part

Comment: @K.Ghosh: what does Liouville's theorem tell you about an an analytic map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: it is constant!

Comment: @K.Ghosh: Yes, such a map must be constant. Be careful: andybenji showed you in the first comment how $\mathbb{C}$ and $D$ are *diffeomorphic* (in particular homeomorphic). What Liouville tells you is that there can be no *analytic* isomorphism because every analytic map $\mathbb{C}\to D$ is constant.